# Update Vue Axios Base Instance with API Token after Login

Tags: vuejs2, axios

In my Vue App (first Vue project, sorry if this might be a basic question) I created an axios base instance like so:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import router from '@/router'

export const API = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://api-url.com',
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('api_token')
    },
    validateStatus: function (status) {

        if (status == 401) {
            router.push('/login');
        } else {
            return status;
        }
    }
})
```

When I login, the API token gets saved this way:

```
localStorage.setItem('api_token', response.data.api_token)
```

After the login thow, the axios base instance will not be updated with the token until a browser reload. How can I change that?

Answer (score 0):

You can update the axios instance like so,

```
export const API = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/',
  withCredentials: false
})

export function getAPI () {
  return API
}

export function setHeader (key, value) {
  API.defaults.headers.common[key] = value
}

export function removeHeader (key) {
  delete API.defaults.headers.common[key]
}
```